# Four lines are drawn on a plane with no two parallel....

Tags: puzzle

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Four lines are drawn on a plane with no two parallel 
>   and no three concurrent.Lines are drawn joining the 
>   points of intersection of the previous four lines. Number of new lines obtained
>   this way is : $\,\,3,\,\, 5, \,\, 2,\,\,12.$

*My Attempt*: [image]

I think the answer will be $2$ but the answer key says it will be $3$.  Can someone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: You need to fully extend the lines.  When you do so, there will be two more intersections, and thus one more line.

Comment: @AJStas thanks a lot sir. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the hints given by @AJStas, I can say that the number of new lines obtained this way will be $3.$

[image]

Comment: And since the lines are in general position, you can predict ${4 \choose 2} = 6$, points of intersection, yielding $3$ new lines.

Comment: @SammyBlack thanks a lot sir. It is another nice way to look at it ...